# prove using induction that for all natural number $n≥2$, $3^n>3n+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, induction

(Answered)

1. base $$3^2>3(2)+1$$
   $$9>6+1$$
   $$9>7$$
   which is true
2. assume $k=n$     $3^k>3n+1$
   should be true for n=k+1
   $$3^{k+1}>3(k+1)+1=3k+4$$
   $$3^{k+1} $$
   $$=3^k*3$$
   $$\gt (3k+1)*3$$
   $$=9k+3$$ $$\gt3k+4$$ because k is a natural number

Is my proof correct?

Comment: I think, you've made a small slip in your final line: it should be $3^k>k+4/3$. For such an expression though, you just have to prove that $\forall k\geqslant2:~3k+1\geqslant k+4/3$, then the last expression will hold true, and the induction will be complete. Though, there is a bit easier (from my pov) way to prove the desired inequality - by considering that $\mathbb{N}_{[2,+\infty)}\subset\mathbb{R}_{[2,+\infty)}$, and further derivatives of lhs and rhs in the real domain

Comment: @o.spectrum Seems like OP is just learning to do induction. So I believe derivatives might be a bit too advanced at this point.

Comment: You should add explanations to you lines of proof.  The first line is want you want to proof and without an explanation I don't know why you are stating it especially as you currently have no idea if it's true. Then you move on and it's not till the third or fourth line I realize the first line was just a statement of what need to be proved and the rest was your attempt to do so (I've never seen a student set up a problem this way).  You proof is okay but 1) you have to prove that $9k + 3> 3k+4$ and 2) you mix up and throw in $n$ rather than $k$ a lot in ways that don't make sense.

Answer (score 5):

You want to prove that $3^{k+1}>3(k+1)+1$, so it's not very good to write this inequality from the beginning. You want to end with it. Start from the left hand side only:

$3^{k+1}=3\cdot 3^k>3(3k+1)=9k+3=3k+(6k+3)\geq3k+4=3(k+1)+1,$

since clearly $6k+3\geq 4$.